# how to overload multiply operator for string in c++

Tags: c++

I have a string "3*ab" i want to overload the * operator and get the output "ababab" is it possible to overload the * operator for string?

ok, So here is the program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class StrMultiply {
public:
    string multiply (string str){
        istringstream iss(str);
        int number;
        string op;
        string st;
        string ret;
        iss >> number;
        iss >> op;
        iss >> st;
        cout<<" Number: "<<number<<endl;
        cout<<" Operator: "<<op<<endl;              
        cout<<" String :"<<st<<endl;
        for(int i=0;i<number;i++){
            ret+=st;
        }
        return ret;
    }
};

int main(){
    StrMultiply S;
    string ret;
    ret =S.multiply("3 * ab");
    cout<<"Returned string is :"<<ret<<endl;
}

Program Output:
 Number: 3
 Operator: *
 String :ab
Returned string is :ababab
```

I want to convert this program and use the multiply operator overloading.

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve] - don't forget to include the error(s).

Comment: You can overload it for e.g. `3 * "ab"` but for `"3 * ab"` you have to actually create a *parser* which parse the string to evaluate it.

Comment: There is not operators inside a string literal! So it is unclear what are you asking for. "getting compilation error" is not a description of a problem, if something doesn't compile show the code and copy paste error message.

Comment: Also, you can't write an operator overload where both operands are basic types or pointers, so `3 * "ab"` can't be overloaded, but `3 * std::string("ab")` can be overloaded, if you really want to.

Comment: Add your code here.

Comment: @GemTaylor: But it is bad to overload operator when no own types are involved. Breaking ODR can happen for example.

Answer (score 0):

To overload the `*` operator in C++, you define the function `operator*`. In your case, you would want to define the function

```
std::string operator*(std::string str, int n);
```

NB: This will only work for expressions of the form `"ab" * 3`, it will not work for expressions of the form `3 * "ab"`. You will have to define the function with parameters reversed for that to work, if you want it that way, that is.

For more information on operator overloading, take a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators